# What is the maven repository for jasperreports-chart-themes?

Tags: maven-2, repository, jasper-reports

I'm searching the repository for jasperreports-chart-themes (groupId : net.sf.jasperreports).

I know that jasperreports lib is here http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports, but there is no track of jasperreports-chart-themes ...

Comment: http://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports-chart-themes/3.7.4/ does that help?

Comment: Yes I saw that, but it's not really "clean" to use alfresco repository in order to have jasperreports libs ...

Comment: Maybe you should request the original developers to publish the jars in maven.org.